# Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init() не существует

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Библиотека подключена, ссылка на неё есть, но почему-то самого класса и метода Init() в пространстве имён нет. Помогите пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Forms.Maps.Init?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ такого нет и не может быть.

Comment: С чего это вдруг? Все стандартные namespace у Xamarin начинаются на **Xamarin.Forms**, а дальше уже идет все остальное через точку (пример: `Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration`), а у вас вдруг слитно `FormsMaps` у стандартного namespace, даже вон пакет зовется [Xamarin.Forms.Maps](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps/). Так с чего вдруг не может быть?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/setup

Comment: Вас не смущает то, что весь сайт выдает белеберду по типу `:::no-loc(Xamarin.Forms):::`? После .net 5 весь сайт майкнософта поехал. Также не удивлюсь, если там будет опечатка. Ну и как доказательство, я могу вам дать [официальный репозиторий](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) xamarin'a, видите там хоть одно название `FormsMaps`? Я нет...

Comment: Там есть [такие](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/f35ae07a0a8471d255f7a1ebdd51499e10e0a4cb/Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android/FormsMaps.cs#L12) классы, тут ок, согласен, но тогда другой вопрос - вы уверены, что у вас ошибка говорит о том, что класса нету? А не о том, что вы его не так используете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ там попросту нет такого класса.